# xcode 6 - red constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

I have been trying to tackle constraints recently.  I have a mildly complex view.  When connecting my constraints some of my constraints turn red.  Simulator still runs, but my labels and buttons are not in place. Why are constraints red?

Comment: Because they are in conflict. Suppose you have a view with a 100 px width constraint. In this view, you have a view with a 80 px width constraint. The leading (left) space to superview constraint is 0px. Now any constraint that would make the trailing (right) space to superview anything other than 20px, will make the situation impossible. In such a situation, the conflicting constraints turn red.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's indicating that there is a problem with your layout.  Either your views are not properly positioned, there is an unresolvable conflict between your constraints, or some properties are ambiguous because constraints are missing.

If you look at the inner left pane there will be a little yellow or red circle with an arrow in it.  If you click that, it will list all the issues for you.

[image]